# ActiveRecord model with two databases simultaneously

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a Ruby on Rails application with two database backends - PostgreSQL and MemSQL (a MySQL-compatible analytics database).

How can I set up a `Model` so that it is persisted to both databases *simultaneously*, such that CREATE, UPDATE and DELETE statements are executed on both, and SELECT queries are executed only on PostgreSQL?

In other words - how can I maintain two database backends always identical using the same ActiveRecord model?

Comment: I know this is not programming related, but, wouldn't be more simple to design a mirror database, so you would have the same data without executing another query in the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually do this by having two model classes. But the cons are many when it comes to composition and complexity. ActiveRecord shares connections by saving them in the base class:

```
class MemSQLBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection configurations['memsql'][Rails.env]
  self.abstract_class = true
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :push_to_memsql!
  def push_to_memsql!
    MemSQLPost.save_or_update!(self.attributes)
  end
end

class MemSQLPost < MemSQLBase
  self.table_name = :posts
  def self.model_name
    ActiveModel::Name.new("Post")
  end
end
```

The awkward part is that to share code between Post and MemSQLPost you have to use modules as they do not share a base class.

It may be possible to circumvent this by monkeypatching the class connection methods:

```
# this class does nothing except holding the connection pool
class MemSQLBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection configurations['memsql'][Rails.env]
  self.abstract_class = true
end

module MemSQLMonkeyPatch
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def connection_pool
      MemSQLBase.connection_pool
    end

    def retrieve_connection
      MemSQLBase.retrieve_connection
    end

    def connected?
      MemSQLBase.connected?
    end

    def remove_connection(klass = self)
      MemSQLBase.remove_connection
    end
  end
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
  after_save :push_to_memsql!
  def push_to_memsql!
    MemSQLPost.save_or_update!(self.attributes)
  end
end

class Post < MemSQLBase
  include MemSQLMonkeyPatch
  self.table_name = :posts
end
```

I have not tested this though so you are on your own.

Comment: There is quite a bit more to this though - you have to somehow apply migrations to both databases (or duplicate them). There are plenty of blog posts about multi-db rails apps that should provide a decent starting point.